# Get the textarea content after the hyperlink in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have few text area elements(which has same names and no id) in a html file like:

    `<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="return foo()">gettext1</a>
    <textarea name="code" cols="10" rows="30">text1</textarea>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="return foo()">gettext2</a>
    <textarea name="code" cols="10" rows="30">text2</textarea>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="return foo()">gettext3</a>
    <textarea name="code" cols="10" rows="30">text3</textarea>`

When user clicks on the any link I want to get the content of the **textarea** which immediately follows this link. How I can access this in **foo** method?

Is it possible without using jquery?

Comment: `$(this).next('textarea').val()` comes to mind, but then you'd need a proper event handler as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
function foo(){
//Gather object in variable using javascript getElementById function
var obj = getElementById('code');

//Use javascript .innerhtml function to grab the contents of the element
obj = obj.innerhtml;

//Display text in console to prove working
console.log(obj);
}
```

Comment: Sure thing. Code has been updated to reflect explanation request

Comment: Wrong. I am getting always the first text area content.

Comment: Ah I see you've updated your question. Will have an updated answer shortly

Comment: Just curious, why are you doing this, or what will this be used for. Just for better context. Maybe there is another way to solve the problem depending on the final product

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
function foo() {
    var comments = $(this).next('textarea').val();
    alert(comments);
    return comments;
}
```

or maybe

```
function foo() {
    var comments = $(this).find("textarea").val();
    alert(comments);
    return comments;
}
```

or

```
function foo() {
    var comments = $("#code").val();
    alert(comments);
    return comments;
}
```

Comment: Correct, if the developer is using jQuery

Comment: Is it possible without using jquery

Comment: Yes, see below answer